# Declaring orm out of struct

Tags: go, orm

I try to use orm with gRPC generated models. But orm packages wants me to add keys in struct, for example:

```
type Model struct {
  ID        uint           `gorm:"primaryKey"` // I think I shouldn't add this in generated file
  CreatedAt time.Time
  UpdatedAt time.Time
  DeletedAt gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"index"`
}
```

> [Doc](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html)

Is there any orm packages that can be configured out of struct or can I add `gorm:"primaryKey"` in generated file